# Подсказки для HTML в PhpStorm

Tags: html, phpstorm, ide

Когда начинаю писать какой-нибудь тег в HTML, то не появляется подсказка, а вот, например, в JS всё появляется:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ctrl + Space ...

Comment: Подсказки для html включены?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте ввести угловую скобку (`<`), или в явном виде вызовите подсказку с помощью `Ctrl + Space`

Кстати, автоподсказки в HTML работают начиная с версии 2021.3, см. https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2021/10/webstorm-2021-3-eap-4/#improved_code_completion_for_html